# Autocomplete and Solr

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, solr

I am trying to build an auto complete using Solr (TermsComponent) and Rails. Now there are several options of doing this using jRails, 'plain' jQuery, autocomplete plugin etc.

What is the best way to do this? Are there any good tutorial for this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [jquery ui autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete) its easy to implement and fully customizable 
you can find example for remote data source [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote)